# Как удалить дубликаты списка если элементы словари?

Tags: python, python-3.x

обязательное условие - алгоритмическая сложность не должна быть O(n^2).

```
[
    {"key1": "value1"},
    {"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2", "k3": "v3"},
    {},
    {},
    {"key1": "value1"},
    {"key1": "value1"},
    {"key2": "value2"}
]
```

Comment: O(n^2) - означает, что ты можешь использовать цикл внутри цикла. Пробегись по всем элементам и сравни каждый с каждым.

Comment: @SergeyK. автор же наоборот пишет, что такая сложность быть не должна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот код, который выведет уникальные словари в порядке их появления в исходном списке.

```
dicts = [
    {"key1": "value1"},
    {"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2", "k3": "v3"},
    {},
    {},
    {"key1": "value1"},
    {"key1": "value1"},
    {"key2": "value2"}
]

known_dicts = set()
result = []


for d in dicts:
    items = tuple(d.items())
    if items not in known_dicts:
        result.append(d)
        known_dicts.add(items)

print(result)
```

Сложность здесь точно будет субквадратичная. И, кажется, даже чуть ли не линейная, если я ничего не упускаю из вида.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Да, сложность тут `O(n)`, потому что поиск в словаре при удачной хэш-функции это `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Предложенное мной ниже решение не удовлетворяет условию: ***алгоритмическая сложность не должна быть O(n^2)*** (спасибо людям в комментариях, которые указали на ошибку) Здесь сложность будет O(n^2).

```
def remove_duplicate(array: List[dict]) -> List:
    unique_array = []
    for elem in array:
        if elem not in unique_array:
            unique_array.append(elem)
    print(unique_array)
```

Всё же я хочу предложить другое решение воспользовавшись не строгостью условия о порядке элементов, предполагаю, что у данного алгоритма сложность меньше чем O(n^2):

```
def remove_duplicate(array: List[dict]) -> List:
    unique_set = {tuple(elem.items()) for elem in array}
    print([dict(elem) for elem in unique_set])
```

Comment: Что такое "понимание списка"? Почему вы думаете, что  временная сложность O (n)???

Comment: Поиск в списке имеет сложность `O(n)`, в отличие от поиска в словаре `O(1)` из уже принятого ответа. Поскольку поиск этот производится внутри цикла, уже имеющего сложность `O(n)`, поэтому ваш вариант имеет сложность `O(n^2)`, в отличие от `O(n)` в уже принятом ответе.

Comment: Да, действиетельно, моя ошибка, спасибо за комментарии сложность будет O(n^2). Предлагаю другое решение